# Best practices when using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on a javascript page using cookies and I was wondering if it is better to use a single cookie which contains multiple values stored in an object or a separate cookie for each value.

Both methods seem to work but is one considered to be a better practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just use what your project requires. If it makes sense to use one cookie, use one cookie. If not, it's not a problem to use more than one.